# Using Scanner to ask for your name

Tags: java

I am working on a java assignment for class. Very basic but I just starting to learn to program and this is my first assignment. The assignment is to write a Java program that asks for your name and then greet you like “hello {name}” in java and I'm using online IDE- Browxy

This is my attempt and reads errors every time I run it.

code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class usersName {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String usersName;
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        usersName = java.util.Scanner;
        System.out.println("Hello, " + usersName! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner` doesn't represent the `String` itself. It's an object that is *able to read* a `String` from the console.

Comment: You have to use a method of the `Scanner` in order to read system input and you will need an instance of `Scanner`, not the class.

Comment: becarefull you have an error at `System.out.println("Hello, " + usersName! ");` use :  `System.out.println("Hello, " + usersName+"! ");`

Comment: and also class names should start with capital letters

Comment: Which kind of error are you facing? Please add the full and exact error message to your question

Comment: it works! thank you for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

look for something like this :

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
    
class usersName {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ))
        {
            String usersName;
            System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
            usersName = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Hello, " + usersName+"! ");
        }catch( Exception e){
            System.out.println("you didn't take any name");
        }    
    }
}`
```